# How to specify the name of the Heroku app for an app pulled from github?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I'm new to Heroku and I'm working with someone on an app via github. I cloned the repo from github, but now when I run heroku commands (e.g. `heroku run python`) I get the following error even though I'm running it from the root of the repo:

```
!    No app specified.   
!    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.
```

What do I need to do to properly configure the app? The commands work if I pass the `--app` flag, but I want to avoid specifying the flag every time.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the message unless you're outside of the app's root folder (the one where you ran `heroku create`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've cloned the repo you need to connect the repo to your Heroku app via

```
heroku git:remote
```

(I guess you may need to use `--app <name>` for one last time here) which will create a `heroku` remote in your git config - the Heroku CLI uses this to figure out your app name moving forwards.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/collab#clone-the-code